# how to perform case sensitive select query from servlets?

Tags: sql-server-2005

I am trying perform case sensitive queries on SQL server but dont know any solution?

Answer (score 2):

> It is dependent on [column collation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187582.aspx).

You should change column collation to case sensitive, like SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CS_AS.

Note: `CS` means case-sensitive, `CI` - case-insensitive).

Answer (score 1):

I did some minor research into this once. Only Postgres seems to do case sensitive queries by default.
There are a few ways to approach this.

case sensitive sql query: http://dotnetslackers.com/SQL/re-61758_Case_Sensitive_or_Insensitive_SQL_Query.aspx and http://www.mssqltips.com/tip.asp?tip=1032

adjust case sensitivity for an entire database: http://web.archive.org/web/20080811231016/http://sqlserver2000.databases.aspfaq.com:80/how-can-i-make-my-sql-queries-case-sensitive.html

It's also possible to adjust case sensitivity for a certain column.

Comment: For ORACLE case sensitive is default too.

Answer (score 1):

No you do not need to change your database schema. You can apply changes on the fly:

```
create table collate_test(
val varchar(50) collate SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
)
go

insert into collate_test values( 'abc');
insert into collate_test values( 'ABC');

select * from collate_test where val = 'abc';

select * from collate_test where val COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CS_AS  = 'abc';

select * from collate_test where val COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CS_AS  = 'ABC';
GO
```